# How can I select a file in a dropdownbox which will then be opened by excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I already created the dropdownbox and it points to a certain directory which contains the .csv files. I can see the files in the dropdownbox, but I want to open them as soon as I click on them. How can I accomplish this in the Visual Basic editor? Here is my code of the dropdownbox.

P.S. I just started programming in Visual Basic.

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub DropdownFiles()
  Dim name

  For Each name In ListDirectory(Path:="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Macro's\", AttrInclude:=vbNormal, AttrExclude:=vbSystem Or vbHidden)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem name
  Next name
End Sub

Function ListDirectory(Path As String, AttrInclude As VbFileAttribute, Optional AttrExclude As VbFileAttribute = False) As Collection
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim Attribs As VbFileAttribute

  Set ListDirectory = New Collection


  Filename = Dir(Path, AttrInclude)

  While Filename <> ""
    Attribs = GetAttr(Path & Filename)
  ' If Attribs And AttrInclude And Not (Attribs And AttrExclude) Then
    If Not (Attribs And AttrExclude) Then
      ListDirectory.Add Filename, Path & Filename
    End If
    Filename = Dir
  Wend
End Function


Private Sub OpenButton()

End Sub
```

The macro which I run. It's located in a directory near the .csv files

```
    Private Sub Macro()
'
' Macro
'

'
    Dim docpath As String
docpath = "TEXT;" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.csv"

    'With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Macro's\Test.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=docpath, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
'        docpath, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
'        .CommandType = 0
        .name = "calllog"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
         ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet1"
    End With
    Range("A1:I9999").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("I2:I829").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("I2:I9999")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = True
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("T1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "60"
    Range("T1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F2:F829").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("G2:G829").Select
    Range("T1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G2:G829").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("T1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A437:I829").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A439:I831")
    Range("A439:I831").Select
    Range("A439:I506").Select
    Range("I506").Activate
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("A438:I505")
    Range("L452").Select
    Range("A2:A436,F2:F436").Select
    Range("F436").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "Sheet1!$A$2:$A$436,Sheet1!$F$2:$F$436")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 304.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -139.5
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Aantal gebelde minuten (Inbound)"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Aantal gebelde minuten (Inbound)"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 32).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 14).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(15, 18).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    Range("O27").Select
    Range("A438:A505,F438:F505").Select
    Range("F505").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "Sheet1!$A$438:$A$505,Sheet1!$F$438:$F$505")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementLeft 312.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").IncrementTop -61.5
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Aantal gebelde minuten (Internal)"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Aantal gebelde minuten (Internal)"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 33).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 33).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    Range("M458").Select
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Range("A507:A831,F507:F831").Select
    Range("F831").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "Sheet1!$A$507:$A$831,Sheet1!$F$507:$F$831")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementLeft 301.5
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementTop -73.5
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Aantal gebelde minuten (Outbound)"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Aantal gebelde minuten (Outbound)"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 33).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 33).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    Range("P535").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").name = "Log"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").name = "Chart"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Log").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Chart").Select
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Log").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Chart").Select
    Range("E19").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.1479166667, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.1770833333, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleWidth 1.1416666667, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 2").ScaleHeight 1.1736111111, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").ScaleWidth 1.1979166667, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").ScaleHeight 1.2361111111, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Left = 85.964
    Selection.Top = 37.09
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementLeft 36
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 3").IncrementTop -0.75
    Sheets("Log").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the dropdown box on the form and select "View Code". In the right top corner of the screen select "Change" event and use the code below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim WbSource As Workbook
Dim pth As String
Dim fnme As String

fnme = ComboBox1.Value
pth = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Macro's\"

Application.Run "CustomMacro", pth & fnme

End Sub
```

If the answer works, please mark as accepted.

I understand that you need to run a macro on the opened workbook now. This can be done in a few ways, here is my suggestion to solve the problem:
1) Try to stay away from `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorksheet` - use variables that are dimensioned as workbooks and worksheets
2) You can pass variables to the macro in several ways - you can make a variable global (I suggest you read up on different levels of variables), but the easiest way is to make the variable an argument for the function.
3) For my solution, I will assume you have two workbooks each with one sheet. I will call them target and source: source is the workbook selected from dropdown menu, and the target is the one where the macro is located. The dropdown box will remember the path to the source and will pass it on to the other macro.

```
Sub CustomMacro(SrceWBPath as String)
Dim WbSource as workbook
Dim WbTarget as workbook
Dim WrkShtSrc as Worksheet
Dim WrkShtTrgt as Worksheet

Set WbTarget = This.Workbook
Set WbSource = Workbooks.Open (SrceWbPath)
Set WrkShtSrc = wbSource.Worksheets("insert_name_of_the_source_worksheet_here")
Set WrkShtTrgt = wbTarget.Worksheets("insert_name_of_the_target_worksheet_here")

'Then insert the rest of your code here, calling the proper sheets as required. Also, move away from `.Select` command - it just consumes a lot of processing time. Define variable such as `Range` and perform operations on them. 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works, but now it opens in a different instance of Excel, so the Macro won't execute. Is there any way to open the .csv in the same excel instance so the macro can run?

Comment: Which macro are you trying to run on the opened workbook? is it a macro from the original workbook with the dropbox?

Comment: if you are running a macro on that workbook then you need to pass the filename to that macro. Could you edit your original question with the macro you are trying to run and the location of it?

Comment: Will do that first thing tomorrow. I don't have access to the files right now.

Comment: I edited my question with the requested code and no, the macro was created outside the dropdown box workbook.

Comment: Give me a few moments, will post a solution

Comment: Damn, I thought you forgot about this post, but I only noticed just now that you edited your original post with the solution. Will try it tomorrow. I'll let you know.